# Does the normal bundle embeds in the tangent bundle.

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, vector-bundles

Given S an embedded submanifold of M, is the normal bundle NS an embedded submanifold of the tangent bundle TM? It seems ituitively to me, but maybe it holds only locally.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: This is evidently not true, even locally. For example, take a closed curve $\gamma:S^1\to\mathbb{R}^3$. The normal bundle has rank $2$, the tangent bundle has rank $1$.

Comment: @QuaereVerum The tangent bundle of $\mathbb{R}^3$ has rank 3, right?

Comment: Oh, my mistake. I thought you were talking about embedding $NS\to TS$. Then yes, for example, by giving $M$ a metric, you get a direct sum decomposition $TM|_S\cong TS\oplus TS^\perp\cong TS\oplus NS$.